# Getting an error in createStatement

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

When I use the following code it runs perfectly.

```
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("select * from users where username=?");
st.setString(1, userId);
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
```

But when I am using the following code, I get an error that `userId` (that I pass as parameter) is an invalid column name.

```
Statement st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from users where username="+userId);
```

Why statement method doesn't work and I have to use `PreparedStatement`?

Comment: I think with your query, you need to wrap `userID` with single and double quotes... Something like `"'userID'"`. But to be honest, you are better off using the first query

Comment: Try it like this `ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from users where username='"+userId+"'");` But `PreparedStatement` is preffered.

Answer (score 5):

User ID is a string (SQL calls this type CHAR or VARCHAR), it must be put in quotes if used in the SQL requests. Like this:

```
select * from users where username='12345'
```

PreparedStatement is much better solution because of the [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You CANNOT just write:

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from users where username=\""+userId+"\"");
                                                      WRONG CODE - ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

because user ID can contains control characters like ['], ["] or [\]. It depends on the SQL server and sometimes are more sophisticated than it looks like. If using PreparedStatement, it is automatically managed by the JDBC driver.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put strings into quotes:

```
Statement st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from users where username=\'"+userId+"\'");
```

`\` is the [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character).

**Note:**
Your prepared statement is the preferred way of handling SQL queries. See @30thh answer as to why (SQL Injection attacks).

Comment: Generally, in Databases, strings are represented in single quotes, not in double quotes, so your query is wrong.

Comment: @Pshemo I just told the author of this question why his code fails, I will not advice on additional security concerns. Especially since he already has a prepared statement in his question, which apparently also works. I will however add the concern behind this as a note to my answer.

Comment: Oh my, sorry you are right. I was reading similar question in second tab and mixed both. Will remove my comments (I need my coffee).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, is better to use the first one. But if you really want to use the second one, you need to put your value into quotes. Simple add the quotes to the value. But is good to create a function to it, if you are going to use it a loot. Like:

```
public String doubleQuoted(String value){
    return "\"" + value + "\"";
}
```

or

```
public String singleQuoted(String value){
    return "'" + value + "'";
}
```

and use

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from users where username="+singleQuoted(userId));
```

Comment: Yes it has. Thats why is better to use the first option. But he doesn`t said why he would like to use the second one instead of the first.

Comment: Thats ok. Coffee time!